# recommended template language for PHP content?

Tags: php, templates, content-management-system, smarty

I am working on a cms/shopping cart.

I want to create a way for designers to update the view of product pages, checkout, custom pages, emails, custom content widgets, etc.

I want this to include simple programming structures such as looping, if tests, formatting etc.

currently the sections either cannot contain programming or i'm using the php's eval() function to process the content. eval() is fine for development, but i don't want to give clients full access to php since this would be a security risk.

I was thinking about using Smarty, but i want to save the content in the database rather than files and it doesn't look like smarty can do that. also, i'm looking for something lighter than smarty since i only need very simple features.

any ideas?

Comment: There are few templating engine on the net, twig is used in symfony 2  framework for exemple, it is relatively powerful can be customized to create twig function, easy to code for designer...http://http://twig.sensiolabs.org/

Comment: @SmasherHell, that should be an answer because that's probably what he's better off using.

Comment: Why do you have to use eval()? You could just do a simple include combined with output buffering.. But anyway, yes, go Twig!

Comment: i installed twig and it looks like it was what i was looking for, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As SmasherHell mentioned in the comments, Twig is a good option; it is used by Symfony and from personal experience it is a very efficient and powerful engine with a fairly straightforward syntax. http://twig.sensiolabs.org/